# Why am I receiving "invalid color argument" error?

Tags: python, pygame

I am following this [tutorial building checkers game](https://github.com/techwithtim/Python-Checkers) but I am receiving this error while building the Checkers piece in the `piece.py` module.

I am trying to print the `RED` pieces and gives me an error with the `self.color` (see error below).

I have followed everything as closely as possible, but I still receive the error.
the code is the following:

Piece.py

```
from checkers.constants import RED, WHITE, SQUARE_SIZE, GREY
import pygame

class Piece:

    PADDING = 15
    OUTLINE = 2

    def __init__(self, row, col, color):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.color = color
        self.king = False

        if self.color == RED: 
            self.direction = -1
        else:
            self.direction = 1

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.calc_pos()

    def calc_pos(self):
        self.x = SQUARE_SIZE * self.col + SQUARE_SIZE // 2
        self.y = SQUARE_SIZE * self.row + SQUARE_SIZE // 2

    def make_king(self):
        self.king = True

    def draw(self, win):
        radius = SQUARE_SIZE//2 - self.PADDING
        pygame.draw.circle(win, GREY, (self.x, self.y), radius + self.OUTLINE)
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), radius)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.color)
```

board.py

```
from .piece import Piece
import pygame
from checkers.constants import BLACK, ROWS, RED, SQUARE_SIZE, COLS, WHITE 

class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        self.selected_piece = None
        self.red_left = self.white_left = 12
        self.red_kings = self.white_kings = 0
        self.create_board()

    def draw_squares(self, win):
        win.fill(BLACK)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(row % 2, COLS, 2):
                pygame.draw.rect(win, RED, (row * SQUARE_SIZE, col*SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))

    def create_board(self):
        for row in range(ROWS):
            self.board.append([])
            for col in range(COLS):
                if col % 2 == ((row + 1) % 2):
                    if row < 3:
                        self.board[row].append(Piece(row, col, WHITE))
                    elif row > 4:
                        self.board[row].append(Piece(row, col, RED))
                    else:
                        self.board[row].append(0)
                else:
                    self.board[row].append(0)

    def draw(self, win):
        self.draw_squares(win)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                piece = self.board[row][col]
                if piece != 0:
                    piece.draw(win)
```

main.py

```
from checkers import piece
import pygame
from checkers.constants import WIDTH, HEIGHT, SQUARE_SIZE, RED
#from checkers import WIDTH, HEIGHT
from checkers.board import Board


FPS = 60

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Checkers')


def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    board = Board()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pass

        board.draw(WIN)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

I run `main.py` and I receive the following error:

```
line 34, in draw pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), radius) 
ValueError:invalid color argument
```

Comment: You left out the most important thing. The error message says: `ValueError: invalid color argument`. How do you instatiate `Piece`? What value do you set for `color`?

Comment: @Matthias I set color as color (please see code included) I instantiate with a class

Comment: Yes, you set `self.color = color`, but that wasn't my question. What is the type and value of the `color` parameter?

Comment: Its `RED` -- comes from the `constants.py` module
`RED = (255, 0, 0)`

Comment: "I run `main.py` ..." What is this mysterious `main.py` that you refer to? It seems to be the code which is causing the error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: One debugging idea is the replace `self.color` by `RED` in the call to `pygame.draw.circle` and rerun the code. Do it again with `BLACK`. Do you still get an error? If so, the problem is with how the constants are defined. If not, the problem is with the values that the passing code (in `main.py`?) is passing to the `Piece` class.

Comment: I have a conditional `if self.color == RED:` 
            self.direction = -1
        else:
            self.direction = 1

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks John, I went ahead and added the `main.py` script and the `board.py` script... as mentioned `RED` is held in the `constant.py` and along with `piece.py` and `board.py` are both in a folder named checkers along with a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: What is `self.color` at that exact point (not what _should_ it be, but what _is_ it)? Print it or use a debugger to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of importing the colors, as you did `from checkers.constants import BLACK, ROWS, RED, SQUARE_SIZE, COLS, WHITE` , you should define them yourself by using RGB. Like this

> RED = (255, 0, 0)

> WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

> BLACK = (0, 0, 0)